# Find Last Inserted Record MS SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I applied 12Lac Insert command in Single table ,
but after some time query terminated , How can I find Last 
Inserted Record 
a)Table don't have created Date column
b)Can not apply order by clause because primary key values are manually generated
c)Last() is not buit in fumction in mssql.

Or any way to find last executed query

There will be some way but not able to figure out

Table contain only primary key constrain no other constrain

Comment: What a good reason to have an identity column in every table!

Comment: is your primary key an identity column? (i.e. id-auto-generating)

Comment: `select top 1 * from table order by identiy_column desc`

Comment: You might want to change that design. It's totally unhelpful for helping in auditing and change tracking.

Comment: it is most probably much easier to just scrap all you have already inserted into that table and then reinsert again with a proper structure (for example having an identity column)

Comment: primary key is is not auto generating it is manual entry,I know it is not good design..

Comment: the question is: is this a support case in which you MUST find out where your insert stopped? or is it just more important to have everything inserted properly. If it is the ladder you should definetly change the table structure for that insert.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Its not possible to remove, table already containing 3.3 cr data , and data is very crucial.

Comment: i think that is just really bad luck then you might just change your insert to only insert values that do not exist already and execute it as often as it takes ;)

Comment: I want to find last record so that i can figure out which was last Insert command executed n then I will execute remaining insert command.

Comment: If you need a one-time quick and dirty solution: just do a manual binary search of your insert statements in the database table. For 1 million records you'll need 20 checks. This works only if you still have the same sequence of insert statements that stopped at some point. Otherwise you're out of luck. See also: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53081/2397

Comment: @MicSim that sounds interesting could you expand on this a little in an answer? seems like the only legit way out of this mess so far...

Answer (score 1):

As per comment request here a quick and dirty manual solution, assuming you've got the list of `INSERT` statements (or the according data) in the same sequence as the issued `INSERT`s. For this example I assume 1 million records.

```
INSERT ... VALUES (1, ...)
...
INSERT ... VALUES (250000, ...)
...
INSERT ... VALUES (500000, ...)
...
INSERT ... VALUES (750000, ...)
...
INSERT ... VALUES (1000000, ...)
```

You just have to find the last PK, that has been inserted. Luckily in this case there is one. So you start doing a manual binary search in the table issuing

```
SELECT pk FROM myTable WHERE pk = 500000
```

If you get a row back, you know it got so far. Continue checking with `pk = 750000`. Then again, if it is there with `pk = 875000`. If 750000 is not there, then the `INSERT`s must have stopped earlier. Then check for `pk = 675000`. This process stops in this case after 20 steps.

It's just plain manual divide and conquer.

Comment: I did this one to find ... :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way.
Unfortunately you have to do this in advance so it helps you.
So if you have, by any chance the `PRIMARY KEYS` you inserted, still at hand go ahead and delete all rows that have those keys:

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE ID IN (id1, id2, ...., idn)
```

Then you enable [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx) for your database (have the db already selected):

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db;
```

Now you also need to enable Change Data Capture for that table, in an example that I've tried I could just run:

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table @source_schema = N'dbo', @source_name = N'tableName', @role_name = null
```

Now you are almost setup! You need to look into your system services and verify that `SQL Server Agent` is running for your DBMS, if it does not capturing will not happen.

Now when you insert something into your table you can select data changes from a new table called `[cdc].[dbo_tableName_CT]`:

```
SELECT [__$start_lsn]
      ,[__$end_lsn]
      ,[__$seqval]
      ,[__$operation]
      ,[__$update_mask]
      ,[ID]
      ,[Value]
  FROM [cdc].[dbo_tableName_CT]
GO
```

An example output of this looks like this:

[image]

you can `order by __$seqval` that should give you the order in which the rows were inserted.

NOTE: this feature seems not to be present in `SQL Server Express`