# SQL Server - resume cursor from last updated row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do a cursor update of a table (milions of rows). The script should resume from last updated row if it would be started again (e.g. in case of a server restart).

What is the best way to resolve this? Create a new table with the last saved id? Use the tables extended propertes to save this info?

Comment: I would rather prefer you to do this by batch mode . 1 ) create temp table with all ids and isloaded = 0 2) select top 10000 id  where isloaded =0 and do the update and set isloaded = 1 for those jobs  3) loop this until all the id's isloaded = 1

Comment: cursors should generally be avoided if what you're trying to do is deal with an entire *set* of data. Updating millions of rows definitely feels like the sort of thing that should be addressed in a set-based manner, if at all possible. (But possibly split into blocks of rows, say 10000 rows at a time, as per Backtrack's comment, if the update is large)

Comment: My question was about saveing the last position. I know how to use cursors or do a batch update, but that's not the problem.

Comment: @Sarzniak , I know that you are \good in SQL , then use "Extended Properties"

Comment: @Sarzniak: Can you add a new field to the table to save last updated time. So you can load data based on that field??

Comment: Remembering the last processed ID *might* be a good idea if: 1) you were going through the table in the order of IDs, and 2) if it was certain that new rows would never have IDs lower than the one remembered or that, even if they did, they would not need to be updated using that particular cursor. However, it is not clear from what little is said in your post whether those two conditions are satisfied in your case.

Comment: If you really need some tracking of changes to a table's contents, there is a feature in SQL Server (not express though) that enables you to do that (which obviously needs to be set up before you do the changes) related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22506272/2186023 reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would add an "UpdateDate" or "LastProcessDate" or some similarly named datetime column to your table and use this. When running your update, simply process any number of records that aren't the max UpdateDate or are null:

```
where UpdateDate < (select max(UpdateDate) from MyTable) or UpdateDate is null
```

It's probably a good idea to grab the max UpdateDate (`@maxUpdateDate`?) at the beginning of your process/loop so it does not change during a batch, and similarly get a new UpdateDate (`@newUpdateDate`?) at the beginning of your process to update each row as you go. A UTC date will work best to avoid DST time changes.

This data would now be a real attribute of your entity, not metadata or a temporary placeholder, and this would seem to be the best way to be transactionally consistent and otherwise fully [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID). It would also be more self-documenting than other methods, and can be indexed should the need arise. A date can also hold important temporal information about your data, whereas IDs and flags do not.

Doing it in this way would make storing data in other tables or extended properties redundant.

Some other thoughts:

- Don't use a temp table that can disappear in many of the scenarios where you haven't processed all rows (connection loss, server restart, etc.).
- Don't use an identity or other ID that can have gaps filled, be reseeded, truncated back to 0, etc.
- The idea of having a max value stored in another table (essentially rolling your own sequence object) has generally been frowned upon and shown to be a dubious practice in SQL Server from what I've read, though I'm oddly having trouble locating a good article right now.
- If at all possible, avoid cursors in favor of batches, and generally avoid batches in favor of full set-based updates.
- `sp_updateextendedproperty` does seem to behave correctly with a rollback, though I'm not sure how locking works with that -- just FYI if you ultimately decide to go down that path.